# Get p-value about contrast hypothesis for rectangular matrix

Tags: r

I am trying to create a contrast in R for a rectangular matrix.

```
pos_c1 = c(1/2,1/2,-1/6,-1/6,-1/6,-1/6,-1/6,-1/6)
posmat.temp = rbind(constant = 1/8,pos_c1)
```

in order to solve the matrix, I have read somewhere to use the function 'pseudoinverse'

```
posmat = pseudoinverse(posmat.temp)
posmat = posmat[, -1]
posmat
```

Then I have associated my matrix with the data:

```
contrasts(datasheet.complete$LastPosition) = posmat
```

but when I make my mixed-effect analysis with lmer(), I do not get the result for the contrast, but for each condition separately. To give an idea, with a square-matrix that calls the function solve(), in the output I get a p_value that tells me how much my contrast hypothesis is confirmed by the data analysis.

```
cl_c1 = c(0,0,-1,1)
cl_c2 = c(0,-1,0,1)
cl_c3 = c(-1,0,0,1)
closuremat.temp = rbind(constant = 1/4,cl_c1,cl_c2,cl_c3)
closuremat = solve(closuremat.temp)
closuremat = closuremat[, -1]
closuremat

contrasts(datasheet.complete$Closure) = closuremat

model = lmer(Score~Closure*ExpertiseType*LastPosition+(1|Participant)+(1|Item), data = datasheet.complete, REML = TRUE)
summary(model)

-> Closurecl_c1   ....   ....   p_value
```

I would expect therefore in the output a parameter called LastPositionpos_c1, but instead I get:

```
LastPosition1   ....   .....   p_value
Lastposition2   ....   .....   p_value
Lastposition3   ....   .....   p_value
....
```

Do you know what is the right function to use to solve a matrix which is not squared, and to obtain the result for the contrast hypothesis? Or can you suggest me how to move?

---

Ok, if I write the following:

```
conditions <- data.frame(Pos=factor(c(2,4,1,2,5,6,7,2,2,2,5,6,3,3,3,8,5,3,4,2,1,4,3,3,2,6,1,8,3,7,5,7,8,3,6,6,1,6,3,7)))
pos_c1 = c(1/2,1/2,-1/6,-1/6,-1/6,-1/6,-1/6,-1/6)
posmat.temp = cbind(pos_c1)
posmat = pseudoinverse(posmat.temp)
posmat = posmat[, -1, drop = FALSE]
posmat
```

I get:

```
     [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]
[1,] 0.75 -0.25 -0.25 -0.25 -0.25 -0.25 -0.25
```

Looking at the other squared contrasts that work fine, it looks to me that this contrast should present 8 rows (conditions) and 1 column (the contrast hypothesis). Am I correct?

Following this fact, I get an error, which makes sense:

```
contrasts(conditions$Pos) = posmat
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c(0.75, -0.25, -0.25, -0.25, -0.25,  : 
  wrong number of contrast matrix rows
```

---

Ok, here is an example of the issue:

```
library(lme4)
library(lmerTest)
library(corpcor)

database <- data.frame(
Clos=factor(c(4,4,1,4,4,3,2,1,2,1,2,2,4,3,1,2,1,4,1,3,2,2,4,4,4,4,2,1,4,2,2,1,4,2,4,2,1,4,4,3)),
Pos=factor(c(2,4,1,2,5,6,7,2,2,2,5,6,3,3,3,8,5,3,4,2,1,4,3,3,2,6,1,8,3,7,5,7,8,3,6,6,1,6,3,7)),
RF=c(8,6,2,9,7,1,7,6,3,4,6,4,5,2,5,5,3,4,1,3,1,2,3,1,2,2,3,1,8,5,2,2,7,1,9,4,5,6,4,2),
Score=c(4,3,3,5,4,3,2,4,5,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,3,2,3,3,5,4,3,4,4,2,3,4,3,4,1,2,2,2,3,4,5,3,1,2)
)
clos_c1 = c(0,0,-1,1)
clos_c2 = c(0,-1,0,1)
clos_c3 = c(-1,0,0,1)
closmat.temp = rbind(constant = 1/4,clos_c1,clos_c2,clos_c3)
closmat = solve(closmat.temp)
closmat = closmat[, -1]
closmat

pos_c1 = c(1/2,1/2,-1/6,-1/6,-1/6,-1/6,-1/6,-1/6)
posmat.temp = rbind(pos_c1)
posmat = pseudoinverse(posmat.temp)
posmat

contrasts(database$Clos) = closmat
contrasts(database$Pos) = posmat

model = lmer(Score~Clos+Pos+(1|RF), data = database, REML = TRUE)
summary(model)
```

The result of the summary(model) is

```
Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error       df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  3.16682    0.23250  8.79795  13.621 3.26e-07 ***
Closclos_c1 -0.04582    0.61284 28.45101  -0.075   0.9409    
Closclos_c2 -0.25304    0.45563 28.59711  -0.555   0.5830    
Closclos_c3 -0.07088    0.49369 28.72373  -0.144   0.8868    
Pos1         0.99056    0.39208 26.60481   2.526   0.0178 *  
Pos2         0.03166    0.45087 28.87030   0.070   0.9445    
Pos3         0.45739    0.56255 26.22149   0.813   0.4235    
Pos4        -0.38971    0.51039 27.77335  -0.764   0.4516    
Pos5         0.19800    0.48213 28.97190   0.411   0.6843    
Pos6        -0.46234    0.52282 26.99040  -0.884   0.3843    
Pos7         0.28973    0.56143 25.70950   0.516   0.6102
```

As you can see, I have the p_value for the 3 contrast hypothesis named Closclos_c1, _c2 and _c3.
I would therefore expect to have the p_value also for the rectangular contrast hypothesis called pos_c1, but instead I have the p_value for 7 out of 8 conditions.

What I would expect instead would be something like:

```
Closclos_c1
Closclos_c2
Closclos_c3
Pospos_c1
```

Comment: Probably `posmat[, -1, drop = FALSE]` will do. However, you don't need to rbind the constant when using the pseudoinverse. So `posmat <- pseudoinverse(rbind(pos_c1))` or equivalently `MASS::ginv(rbind(pos_c1))` should be all you need.

Comment: Also, you can name the contrast via `colnames(posmat) <- ".pos_c1"`.

Comment: Thank you @statmerkur, now I have another problem. When setting the contrast for my parameter, I get the error "Error in cm[, 1L:nc] <- value : replacement has length zero"

Comment: I can have a look into it if you provide a reproducible example.

Comment: @statmerkur, you are right. I guess that there was a problem that something was "remembered", and got a false feedback. Now that I had to restart R, I get a different message, First of all, I understand that my 'posmat' (8 conditions) presents 7 columns (that I guess should be 8 rows). Secndly, the result of the contrast is "Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c(0.75, -0.25, -0.25, -0.25, -0.25,  : 
  wrong number of contrast matrix rows". I update now this problem in the main text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When computing the generalized inverse (aka pseudoinverse) of a matrix in order to specify custom contrasts in R one does not need to `rbind` (not to be confused with `cbind`) a constant to that matrix.

The following code shows how the desired matrix can be computed. Note that I use `MASS::ginv()` here but `corpcor::pseudoinverse()` works equally well.

```
conditions <- data.frame(Pos=factor(c(2,4,1,2,5,6,7,2,2,2,5,6,3,3,3,8,5,3,4,2,1,4,3,3,2,6,1,8,3,7,5,7,8,3,6,6,1,6,3,7)))
pos_c1 <- c(1/2,1/2,-1/6,-1/6,-1/6,-1/6,-1/6,-1/6)

posmat.temp1 <- rbind(pos_c1)
posmat1 <- MASS::ginv(posmat.temp1)
posmat1
      [,1]
[1,]  0.75
[2,]  0.75
[3,] -0.25
[4,] -0.25
[5,] -0.25
[6,] -0.25
[7,] -0.25
[8,] -0.25
```

If you really want to `rbind` the constant to the matrix and delete it afterwards, this can be achieved with the following code. `drop = FALSE` is important in this case as it will prevent R from coercing the matrix to a vector.

```
posmat.temp2 <- rbind(constant = 1/8, pos_c1)
posmat2 <- MASS::ginv(posmat.temp2)
posmat2 <- posmat2[, -1, drop = FALSE]

all.equal(posmat1, posmat2)
[1] TRUE
```

It is easy to name the contrast with:

```
colnames(posmat1) <- ".pos_c1"
```

A nice feature of R comes in handy now, it automatically adds some orthogonal contrasts to fill in the missing columns of the contrast matrix:

```
contrasts(conditions$Pos) <- posmat1
contrasts(conditions$Pos)
     .pos_c1                                                                  
1    0.75 -0.2886751 -0.2886751 -0.2886751 -0.2886751 -0.2886751 -0.2886751
2    0.75  0.2886751  0.2886751  0.2886751  0.2886751  0.2886751  0.2886751
3   -0.25  0.8333333 -0.1666667 -0.1666667 -0.1666667 -0.1666667 -0.1666667
4   -0.25 -0.1666667  0.8333333 -0.1666667 -0.1666667 -0.1666667 -0.1666667
5   -0.25 -0.1666667 -0.1666667  0.8333333 -0.1666667 -0.1666667 -0.1666667
6   -0.25 -0.1666667 -0.1666667 -0.1666667  0.8333333 -0.1666667 -0.1666667
7   -0.25 -0.1666667 -0.1666667 -0.1666667 -0.1666667  0.8333333 -0.1666667
8   -0.25 -0.1666667 -0.1666667 -0.1666667 -0.1666667 -0.1666667  0.8333333
```

---

Regarding your last example:

You *do* get the p-value for the contrast `pos_c1` but `corpcor::pseudoinverse()` and `MASS::ginv()`, unlike `solve()`, drop the column/row names. Therefore you have to manually set the desired name for your contrast.
If you add `colnames(posmat) <- "pos_c1"`  before you assign the matrix to the factor you get the same fixed effects table, but now "Pos1" has the expected name "Pospos_c1".

```
[...]
pos_c1 = c(1/2,1/2,-1/6,-1/6,-1/6,-1/6,-1/6,-1/6)
posmat.temp = rbind(pos_c1)
posmat = pseudoinverse(posmat.temp)
colnames(posmat) <- "pos_c1"
contrasts(database$Clos) = closmat
contrasts(database$Pos) = posmat
model = lmer(Score~Clos+Pos+(1|RF), data = database, REML = TRUE)
summary(model)
[...]
Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error       df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  3.16682    0.23250  8.79800  13.621 3.26e-07 ***
Closclos_c1 -0.04582    0.61284 28.45100  -0.075   0.9409    
Closclos_c2 -0.25304    0.45563 28.59700  -0.555   0.5830    
Closclos_c3 -0.07088    0.49369 28.72400  -0.144   0.8868    
Pospos_c1    0.99056    0.39208 26.60500   2.526   0.0178 *  
Pos          0.03166    0.45087 28.87000   0.070   0.9445    
Pos          0.45739    0.56255 26.22100   0.813   0.4235    
Pos         -0.38971    0.51039 27.77300  -0.764   0.4516    
Pos          0.19800    0.48213 28.97200   0.411   0.6843    
Pos         -0.46234    0.52282 26.99000  -0.884   0.3843    
Pos          0.28973    0.56143 25.71000   0.516   0.6102 
[...]
```

Comment: that's great! I have solved one issue. I am going towards my goal. Unfortunately I am still unable to get the p_value for the contrast. Any advice?

Comment: @Luca Danieli: Please, again, provide a reproducible example. Are you using `lmerTest`?

Comment: ok, I have added a complete reproducible example above. Yes, I am using lmerTest

Comment: @Luca Danieli: see my edit. Hope this clears things up.

Comment: Yes! This is exactly the situation I had in the beginning, but as I did not understand that the name is fundamental to read the output, I did not give it much importance. I get indeed an error about 'duplicate rows': 'Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = value) : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed'. How's that you don't?

Comment: @Luca Danieli: Mhm that sounds strange. Added another code snippet. Can you compare your code line by line with mine?

Comment: Yes, it has happened with your code as well. I restarted R to have a fresh environment and I get the same warning. I am on Ubuntu 18.04. Maybe that's why?

Comment: @Luca Danieli: Sorry, but I don't know why this happens. Are you sure that `colnames(posmat) <- "pos_c1"` causes the problem, i. e. that your code runs fine without this line?

Comment: Yes. I have checked on both the example above and in the actual code, and have the same issue. Well, no prob. I will open another ticket on that specific issue, or will email the mailing-list describing the problem and asking for possible solutions, suggestions or alternatives. Thanks anyway for all the time you have spent trying to help me!! (Btw, as I see in your example above, it's just a matter of name. The data is the same in any case, so I can figure out which one is the correct line, hopefully)

Comment: @Luca Danieli: I'm glad I could help. You are welcome to accept my answer by clicking the check-mark next to it if my answer worked for you.